# jquery mobile + cordova get photo and post via php mail

Tags: jquery, forms, cordova, post, mobile

I am using Jquery mobile 1.4.5 and cordova for a mobile app.

Currently I want to send via php mail service a photo taken from the user or a photo from his photo gallery.

So far the js from cordova api:

```
    var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
  // console.log(imageData);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  // Uncomment to view the image file URI
  // console.log(imageURI);

  // Get image handle
  //
  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

  // Unhide image elements
  //
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';

  // Show the captured photo
  // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
  //
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

// A button will call this function

// Called if something bad happens.
//
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Then I use a simple form in the html:

```
<form method="post" action="my_server/mail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
 <input name="attachment" type="file" id="attachment" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" class="btn">
     </form>
```

The mail.php is

```
                            <?php
            session_start();
            if(isset($_POST['mail'])){
                // antiflood controle
                if (!empty($_SESSION['antiflood']))
                {
                    $seconde = 20; 
                    $tijd = time() - $_SESSION['antiflood'];
                    if($tijd < $seconde)
                        $antiflood = 1;
                }


                $email_to = "my_email";
                $email_subject = "MOBILE form"; 


                /* GET File Variables */
                $attachment = $field_file = $_POST['attachment'];
                $tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
                $fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
                $fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 

                $error_message = "";
                $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
              if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
                $error_message = "error";
              }
                $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
              if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
                $error_message = "error";
              }
              if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
                $error_message = "error";
              }
              if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
              $message_errorr = "Error send, please try again";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message_errorr');</script>";
            echo "<script language=javascript> javascript:history.back();</script>";

              }
                  function clean_string($string) {
                  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
                  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
                }
                $datum = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');

                $email_message = "===================================================\n";
                $email_message .= "Mobile contact form " . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "\n";
                $email_message .= "===================================================\n\n";
                $email_message .= "Attachment: ".clean_string($fileName)."\n\n";
                $email_message .= "Send on " . $datum . " from IP address " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n\n";
                $email_message .= "===================================================\n";
                $email_message .= ":\n";
                $email_message .=   "===================================================\n\n";
                $email_message .= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

              // create email headers
              $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
                        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
             if (!empty($tmpName)) 
                {
                      /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
                      $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb');
                      $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName));
                      fclose($file); 
                        /* a boundary string */
                      $randomVal = md5(time());
                      $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x";

                      /* Header for File Attachment */
                      $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
                      $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
                      $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\"";


                      /* Multipart Boundary above message */
                      $email_message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
                      "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
                      "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
                      $email_message . "\n\n";

                      /* Encoding file data */
                      $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

                      /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
                      $email_message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" .
                      "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" .
                      " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" .
                      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                      $data . "\n\n" .
                      "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n";
                }
             if (($error_message == "") && ($antiflood == "")) 
              {
                $_SESSION['antiflood'] = time();
                  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
                  $message = "Succesfully send, please wait for our responce";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
                  echo "<script language=javascript> javascript:history.back();</script>";

              }
              else
              {$message_errorr = "Error send, please try again";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message_errorr');</script>";
              echo "<script language=javascript> javascript:history.back();</script>";

              }  
            } 
            ?>
```

My querstion is, how can I add into the form that is posted the camera photo that the user has taken? with `id="smallImage"` ?

thnx!

Comment: you can use an input type file to have the image on the form (it doesn't work in some android versions), and send the form using an AJAX call to the mail.php, or you can use the camera plugin as you already did and the file transfer plugin to send the image to the server

Comment: I have managed to get a camera or a library photo with the cordova api to be send to a server through php, however i want this to pass through form method="post"  data-ajax="false", how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I manage to both send my form and upload both camera captured image (via cordova camera api) and attachment with:

```
function upload() {
var img = document.getElementById('image');
var imageURI = img.src;
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
var params = new Object();
options.params = params;
options.chunkedMode = false;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, "server/upload.php", win, fail,
    options);
}
```

and

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function runscript()
{ 
upload();
}
</SCRIPT>
```

while the html submit button is

```
 <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" class="btn" onClick="runscript()">
```

I dont know if it is a good practice.